# How tight should a lens be screwed onto a Leica Screw Mount?

Tags: lens, canon, leica, screw-mount

I have a Canon 7 rangefinder. How tight should a lens be screwed onto it?

Answer (score 1):

Any LTM cameras (and enlargers!) I've used have had a pretty hard stop when the lens is threaded on the whole way. Trying to over-tighten could break or bend something. As long as the lens is snug you should be good.